# Error in Power BI Desktop: Couldn't retrieve the data for this visual. Please try again later

Tags: powerbi

I have a PBIX file with hard coded data in it. 
When opening this file in another computer, I see the error: "Couldn't retrieve the data for this visual. Please try again later." in all visualizations - none is displayed.
I checked the data tables, the relationships, the measures, it's all there, but the visualizations are not.

This is the error message I got from "Copy Details":

```
 Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Timestamp:
2017-05-29T20:42:48.6211672Z

Local Time:
2017-05-29T21:42:48.6211672+01:00

Product Version:
2.46.4732.721 (PBIDesktop) (x64)

Release:
May, 2017

IE Version:
9.0.8112.16421

OS Version:
Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7600.0 (x64 pt-PT)

CLR Version:
4.5.2 or later [Release Number = 379893]

Workbook Package Info:
1* - pt-PT, Query Groups: 0, fastCombine: Disabled, runBackgroundAnalysis: True.

Peak Working Set:
428 MB

Private Memory:
363 MB

Peak Virtual Memory:
1.75 GB

Error Message:
Couldn't retrieve the data for this visual. Please try again later.

User ID:
53363366-9a71-40bb-a970-4287fc81aa55

Session ID:
5a3ac179-0f99-4746-bc5b-04903de38c9c

Telemetry Enabled:
True

Model Default Mode:
Import

Snapshot Trace Logs:
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\FrownSnapShot1590715337.zip

Performance Trace Logs:
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\PerformanceTraces.zip

Enabled Preview Features:
PBI_shapeMapVisualEnabled
PBI_pivotTableVisualEnabled
PBI_numericSlicerEnabled
PBI_daxTemplatesEnabled
PBI_relativeDateSlicer

Disabled Preview Features:
PBI_Impala
PBI_Snowflake
PBI_EnableReportTheme
PBI_allowBiDiCrossFilterInDirectQuery
PBI_esriEnabled
PBI_SpanishLinguisticsEnabled
PBI_PbiServiceLiveConnect

Disabled DirectQuery Options:
PBI_DirectQuery_Unrestricted

Cloud:
GlobalCloud

Activity ID:
5a3ac179-0f99-4746-bc5b-04903de38c9c

Time:
Mon May 29 2017 21:42:40 GMT+0100 (Hora de Verão de GMT)

Version:
2.46.4732.721 (PBIDesktop)

Error Code:
OpenConnectionError

OData Error Message:
Failed to open the MSOLAP connection.

DPI Scale:
100%

Supported Services:
Power BI

Formulas:


section Section1;

shared Financeiros = let
    Origem = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("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", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Ano = _t, #" Vendas e serviços prestados " = _t, #"Margem Bruta" = _t, #" EBITDA " = _t, #"Margem EBITDA" = _t, #" EBIT " = _t, #"Margem EBIT" = _t, #"Rentabilidade dos capitais próprios" = _t, #"Rentabilidade operacional do ativo" = _t, #"Rotação do ativo" = _t, #"Rentabilidade líquida do ativo" = _t, #"Rentabilidade líquida das vendas" = _t, #"Resultados Líquidos" = _t, #" Prazo médio de pagamentos (dias) " = _t, #" Prazo médio de recebimentos (dias) " = _t, #" Nº de dias de inventário " = _t, #" Duração do ciclo de tesouraria (dias) " = _t, #" Grau de liquidez geral " = _t, #" Grau de liquidez reduzida " = _t, #" Grau de liquidez imediata " = _t, #" Fundo de maneio (working capital) " = _t, #" Debt-to-equity ratio " = _t, #" Interest cover " = _t, #"Long term debt-to-assets" = _t, #"Rácio de solvabilidade" = _t, #"Autonomia financeira" = _t, #" Total do ativo " = _t, #"Taxa efetiva de imposto" = _t, #" Resultado operacional líquido de impostos (ROLI) " = _t, #" Capital investido " = _t, #"Taxa de investimento" = _t, #" Free cash flow " = _t, #" Cash flow operacional " = _t, #" Cash flow de investimento " = _t, #" Fluxo líquido de tesouraria " = _t, #" Z - Score " = _t]),
    #"Tipo Alterado1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Origem,{{"Ano", type date}, {" Vendas e serviços prestados ", type number}, {"Margem Bruta", type number}, {" EBITDA ", type number}, {"Margem EBITDA", type number}, {" EBIT ", type number}, {"Margem EBIT", type number}, {"Rentabilidade dos capitais próprios", type number}, {"Rentabilidade operacional do ativo", type number}, {"Rotação do ativo", type number}, {"Rentabilidade líquida do ativo", type number}, {"Rentabilidade líquida das vendas", type number}, {"Resultados Líquidos", type number}, {" Prazo médio de pagamentos (dias) ", type number}, {" Prazo médio de recebimentos (dias) ", type number}, {" Nº de dias de inventário ", type number}, {" Duração do ciclo de tesouraria (dias) ", type number}, {" Grau de liquidez geral ", type number}, {" Grau de liquidez reduzida ", type number}, {" Grau de liquidez imediata ", type number}, {" Fundo de maneio (working capital) ", type number}, {" Debt-to-equity ratio ", type number}, {" Interest cover ", type number}, {"Long term debt-to-assets", type number}, {"Rácio de solvabilidade", type number}, {"Autonomia financeira", type number}, {" Total do ativo ", type number}, {"Taxa efetiva de imposto", type number}, {" Resultado operacional líquido de impostos (ROLI) ", type number}, {" Capital investido ", type number}, {"Taxa de investimento", type number}, {" Free cash flow ", type number}, {" Cash flow operacional ", type number}, {" Cash flow de investimento ", type number}, {" Fluxo líquido de tesouraria ", type number}, {" Z - Score ", type number}}),
    #"Colunas com Nome Mudado" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Tipo Alterado1",{{"Ano", "Data"}})
in
    #"Colunas com Nome Mudado";

shared #"Vendas por produto" = let
    Origem = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("XVFbjgMxCLtLv6kE5hE4S9X7X2OBqVadaqQhJLbB8Ho9VJ6CJ5jPgx56mLkjcEWxT773b/qC58I1isw8dUAKFIW7Y6giXJTq8HkrZJFHf3eZGpnMYwNyPwMW4MR//g2XaUZhBtIaKhIehK0vFi5kvNRSBqXgTpd+suYoVUTkOusWyftv2/Q5QV6c249FI09OdpMZfyYhSXbAkym3HsHglxEpJmntdcN2yBymd5Xp2dh6goVgXRUOpZkqtjxSqNyvjFOUhC1/PE1B8/js6RPDrsj2szeZAVsXOr2pKWk9MFpHgLQj7FG1e2a5U2ewWuxOdT4u29ha9EqaOytRo2qn7z8=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Ano = _t, #"Produto A" = _t, #" Produto B " = _t, #"Produto C" = _t, #" Serviços " = _t]),
    #"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Origem,{{"Ano", type date}, {"Produto A", type number}, {" Produto B ", type number}, {"Produto C", type number}, {" Serviços ", type number}}),
    #"Outras Colunas Convertidas Em Valores" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Tipo Alterado", {"Ano"}, "Atributo", "Valor"),
    #"Colunas com Nome Mudado" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Outras Colunas Convertidas Em Valores",{{"Atributo", "Produto"}})
in
    #"Colunas com Nome Mudado";

shared Geografia = let
    Origem = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bZU7jhsxDEDv4noX4E+kVKZIugDpFy6MFJtiYQfe5Ew5SC4WibPxcEQZMDSwHyg9kuK8vJwYn5GeCcBOT6dvt/uv36+Xt/6o0D9jxf7f6fw0kZ/ff16uPy79CW0DsYgtwC/3y/XvHwdxA620Bffp+np7G9hHuGKyoL5e7vfb99v7ADZOeD5ePYoICrS+khbATAaRgsVFVLVkMIj8BxmoZfBhUqG6bxfPVDAhJPR4DeoUrx1dinYLXytZJoOLso5dsFbiDAYXIPa90VQyuFcFFYcSg2YquCCRqeem2jHbrhhd+s7sBTSgTEYXE/G0l1XI4MIKxV3K5OLgw0XJxqnVsGYqupg19LoQTvFwcrGKNFxAtGZydyE1LyAaN8tgvCxm5mtti70fLoWLJxFWJ4y3ZeOU8Vg/P3a8LdJgJLv0DmqZjFUR8g4TKYuQwYRA3KSfaRHxYYLQCrlxY8tcvC+l35SxstC0Nc89Vr0bRWyaTU6GukD1X1BG2hMYbQybNyMpZXDvscYjOyaNMxVdehbJD8BtcpFpIJNsA7nqNBmd3F34Y3JzmtwOBhet2+Q2BsngPse2jY1oQR1cnCPjyaRMJr1nfMQDV8hkqEodSR4Rm7UMBpMq7L0jjRbgbqIwsFKgZCqYjBOOtmk2mejRpE8QL6giCGYymPDWD1h1nmE6mdRW/Z3Qh04G99uCzN6HhEyZCy7g3/P5Hw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Ano = _t, País = _t, Vendas = _t, Target = _t]),
    #"Valor Substituído" = Table.ReplaceValue(Origem,".","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Vendas", "Target"}),
    #"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Valor Substituído",{{"Vendas", Int64.Type}, {"Target", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Colunas com Nome Mudado" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Tipo Alterado",{{"Ano", "Data"}}),
    #"Tipo Alterado1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Colunas com Nome Mudado",{{"Data", type date}})
in
    #"Tipo Alterado1";

shared #"Não Financeiros" = let
    Origem = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bY+7DcAwCER3cZ1I/GzDLFH2XyMcVYjSXPMecFzXUD5ZTiHa4xgqlOlcucd9vLiDr8iMcp06BzG2TCZVCNqEWmqTIfDGhvAuAFkIBGWc848ANGVCMK8m1gWcnbs6LK2S0gWgGRhl578OWL50ZQrVie8XQMvxi6ijsWeH+wE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Ano = _t, #"Nº de clientes" = _t, #"Nº de produtos" = _t, #"Índice de satisfação do cliente" = _t]),
    #"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Origem,{{"Ano", type date}, {"Nº de clientes", Int64.Type}, {"Nº de produtos", Int64.Type}, {"Índice de satisfação do cliente", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Colunas com Nome Mudado" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Tipo Alterado",{{"Ano", "Data"}})
in
    #"Colunas com Nome Mudado";

shared Demonstrações = let
    Origem = Financeiros,
    #"Outras Colunas Convertidas Em Valores" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Origem, {"Data"}, "Atributo", "Valor"),
    #"Colunas com Nome Mudado" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Outras Colunas Convertidas Em Valores",{{"Atributo", "Indicador"}}),
    #"Linhas Filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(#"Colunas com Nome Mudado", each ([Indicador] = " EBIT " or [Indicador] = " EBITDA " or [Indicador] = " Fluxo líquido de tesouraria " or [Indicador] = " Free cash flow " or [Indicador] = " Resultado operacional líquido de impostos (ROLI) " or [Indicador] = " Total do ativo " or [Indicador] = " Vendas e serviços prestados " or [Indicador] = "Resultados Líquidos"))
in
    #"Linhas Filtradas";

shared ValoresComo = let
    Origem = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCkvMyS9SKEpNzFHSUTJUitWJVvLNzMlILEotBgkYGBjAxQ5vhYuBhWMB", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Mostrar Valores Como" = _t, DividePor = _t]),
    #"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Origem,{{"Mostrar Valores Como", type text}, {"DividePor", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Tipo Alterado";
```

Comment: What happens when you create a new equivalent visualisation? When you refresh data/individual tables? Do your computers have different cultures (locales)?

Comment: When creating a new visual in the same file, I get the same error. Same locales.

Comment: You could try removing tables one by one to see if there's a specific one causing the problem. You could try removing non-international characters from object names, e g "ç", "õ".